# DIV with position:absolute to dynamically extend to bottom of viewport?

Tags: html, css, position, height, absolute

Is it possible to specify the max-height of a DIV with position:absolute such that if it would reach past the viewport downwards, a scrollbar appears?
I.e., to user "overflow-y: scroll;" without having to specify the height statically? (Such that it works even if you resize the window.)

Here's what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/x5efqtv2/2/
(And also see below)

P.S.: I could solve it with JavaScript, I'm interested in pure CSS solutions, if there's any.

Thanks!

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;  /* just to see where the DIVs exactly are */
    margin: 5px;    /* ditto */
}
.float-over-content {
    position: absolute; 
    max-height: 100px;  
    overflow-y: scroll; /* works with static max-height only? */
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>    
  <div id="upper">This one is above the position:absolute one</div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    <!-- this is needed for position:absolute below to put the div under "upper" -- or so I think -->
    <div class="float-over-content">
    <!-- I WANT TO DEFINE THE MAX-HEIGHT OF THIS DIV SUCH THAT IF IT REACHES THE BOTTOM OF THE VIEWPORT, A SCROLL BAR SHOULD APPEAR: (AS OPPOSED TO NOW, WHEN ITS HEIGHT REACHES 100px) -->
    Make this reach exactly to the bottom<br/>
    <!-- X times... -->
    Make this reach exactly to the bottom<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lower">
    This one is "behind" the position:absolute one (it partially covers this one)
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: in case you know the height of the upper element you can do max-height:calc(100vh - h); where h is the known height

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif, unfortunately I don't know the height of the upper element. (And in real life it's not even only one DIV, but some more content above.) Is getting it by JS the only option?

Comment: Actually, I don't see any pure CSS solution but keep waiting, probably someone will come with some magic ;)

Answer (score 0):

What Temani said in the comment. Use the calc function and the view height (vh) of the viewport. Check out the code snippet below. I added a button that will add more lines of text to the element and you can see it expand to fit the viewport with the overflow becoming scroll content.

```js
document.getElementById("add-a-line").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("float-over-content").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','Make this reach exactly to the bottom<br/>' );
});
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;  /* just to see where the DIVs exactly are */
    margin: 5px;    /* ditto */
}
#float-over-content {
    position: absolute; 
    max-height: calc(100vh - 47.4px);  
    overflow-y: scroll; /* works with static max-height only? */
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
}

#add-a-line{
  position:fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<body>    
  <div id="upper">This one is above the position:absolute one</div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    <!-- this is needed for position:absolute below to put the div under "upper" -- or so I think -->
    <div id="float-over-content">
    <!-- I WANT TO DEFINE THE MAX-HEIGHT OF THIS DIV SUCH THAT IF IT REACHES THE BOTTOM OF THE VIEWPORT, A SCROLL BAR SHOULD APPEAR: (AS OPPOSED TO NOW, WHEN ITS HEIGHT REACHES 100px) -->
    Make this reach exactly to the bottom<br/>
    <!-- X times... -->
    Make this reach exactly to the bottom<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lower">
    This one is "behind" the position:absolute one (it partially covers this one)
  </div>
  
  <div id="add-a-line">
    Click to add a line
  </div>
</body>
```